# How to unset environment variable for a container if it's not set on host with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

An example I've a `.env` file along with `docker-compose.yml` and some service definition that grabs an environment variable from the `.env` file through interpolation.

.env

```
MY_VAR='my-value'
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  my_service:
    environment:
      MY_VAR: ${MY_VAR}
```

Note, I'm not setting the default, if I remove MY_VAR from the .env file I will get empty string as the value for the var and the follwing message (which are also described in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/12-interpolation/))

```
WARNING: The MY_VAR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

What I want docker-compose to do is to also unset the variable for the container instead of defaulting to a black string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose has a dedicated syntax for passing through a value from the host environment or elsewhere.  Put no value at all for the `environment:` value, or just put the variable name if you're using the list form of `environment:`.  If the value isn't provided in `.env` or in the host environment, the variable won't be set in the container either.

```yaml
environment:
  MY_VAR:
  # FOO: bar
```

```yaml
environment:
  - MY_VAR
  # - FOO=bar
```

Here's a quick complete Compose file that demonstrates this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  foo:
    image: busybox
    command: sh -c 'echo $${MY_VAR-unset}'
    environment:
      MY_VAR:
```

If you run `docker-compose up`, that shell expansion will print `unset` if `MY_VAR` isn't set, and its contents otherwise; and more specifically, it will print an empty string if `MY_VAR` is set but empty.  You can experiment with different settings here and see what comes out

```bash
docker-compose up                      # "unset"
MY_VAR=foo docker-compose up           # "foo"
MY_VAR= docker-compose up              # empty
echo MY_VAR= >.env; docker-compose up  # empty
```

Comment: Thanks @David Maze that's exactly what I was looking for. One limitation I see with this compared to map syntax + interpolation is that you can't alias the variable, but I can't see any use case where this can be a problem.